# How can I recover data from local realm db?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In my code, I have `Realm().deleteAll()` function on device validation failure. Can I recover and read data from Realm file manually after that operation? For now, Realm file is 10 mb size, but have 0 entity. Seems like entities is not deleted from file, but it can't be shown after delete operation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won't be able to recover the data deleted from your realm with a `.deleteAll()` call. From the Realm [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#deleting-objects):

*"You can also delete all objects stored in a Realm. Note the Realm file will maintain its size on disk to efficiently reuse that space for future objects."*

```
// Delete all objects from the realm
try! realm.write {
    realm.deleteAll()
}
```